# Is there a faster way of accomplishing this in c?

Tags: c, optimization

So I have a variable value that represents an angle in degrees. I do operations with this value very often in my code, so I also need to check if its value is still in [-180, +180] range very often.

Currently, I'm doing it with this piece of code:

```
if (value > 180)
    value -= 360;
else if (value < -180)
    value += 360;
```

Are there any faster ways of accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: @2b-t HOw should a ternary operator do that _faster_?!? Mind to elaborate please? Just having fewer lines of code, doesn't mean that the emitted assembly code would be any faster, or different at all.

Comment: @2b-t _"How are you supposed to make this faster?"_ You aren't. Trying to be smarter than modern c or c++ compilers to beat out more performance there, usually miserably fail :-P

Comment: Your code doesn't work if `value` is greater than 540 or less than -540. There are two representations of 180 degrees (180 and -180), otherwise you can use some variant of an expression involving `%360` (heavily tweaked if you really want it in the range -180 to 180) to get it to work no matter the input value.

Comment: What are your current benchmark results? Which micro-architecture (assuming x86) specifically do you want to optimize for? Are we talking size or speed optimization?

Comment: i guess you want to make it a function to use it easily

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: it is quite optimal

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I misinterpreted what he/she wanted to achieve. Faster does not necessarily mean *computationally faster*  but could also mean more concise. And to be honest you can be quite a bit faster than modern C++ compilers e.g. by using manual vector intrinsics other than relying on auto-vectorisation. The statement "modern C++ compiler so good bla bla bla" gets thrown around a lot but is wrong. There are things a C++ compiler can't do even with compilation flags like `-funsafe-math-optimizations`. But sure there is no point to optimise this...

Comment: @2b-t The reason why the "modern C++ compiler so good bla bla bla" gets "thrown around a lot" is questions like these : people thinking they can somehow sprinkle their code with magical assembly or weird compiler-specific features to make a sequence of comparison-based `if`s "faster". At the same time, they do not have a frame of reference to compare the new solution against, their code is not profiled to ensure that a given sequence is actually a bottleneck, or the performance "problem" is non-existent.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Re “Your code doesn't work if `value` is greater than 540 or less than -540”: There is insufficient basis to conclude that. The question does not state `value` may reach arbitrary values; it may go out of bounds only by at most 360 between checks, in which case the code shown suffices.

Comment: You can maintain the angle in a unit that is a power-of-two fraction of a circle instead of degrees, such as 1/512th of a circle. Then masking the right bits, as with `value &= 0x1ffu`, would reduce the angle to the interval [0, one circle). If you need to maintain a symmetric interval around zero, you could maintain the angle in 1/65536ths of a circle, keep `value` as a 16-bit signed integer, and ensure that the compiler you use has a wider `int` and defines conversions to that the 16-bit signed integer type to wrap.

Comment: @PaulHankin You went a little overboard with that :P The code does work because I do this check every time i change value, and it is assumed that it doesnt change by more than 180 degrees.

Comment: In the latter case, no explicit reduction is necessary; the angle will be reduced every time it is stored in `value`. The cost may be free on some processors and will likely be slight on most.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh wow, that seems pretty good, I will try that, thanks! I'm losing accuracy this way, but it might not be relevant for my application anyways.

Comment: I agree you should leave it to the compiler and maybe make it a function too.

Comment: Why not `[0, 360]` (`[0, 360[`)?

Comment: @pmg Why not [0, 360] range? That's fine too, i would still need to check if it's less than 0 or over 360 either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain the angle in a unit that is a power-of-two fraction of a circle instead of degrees, such as 1/512<sup>th</sup> of a circle. Then masking the right bits, as with `value &= 0x1ffu`, would reduce the angle to the interval [0, one circle). If you need to maintain a symmetric interval around zero, you could maintain the angle in 1/65536<sup>th</sup> of a circle, keep `value` as a 16-bit signed integer, and ensure that the compiler you use has a wider `int` and defines conversions to that the 16-bit signed integer type to wrap.

In the latter case, no explicit reduction is necessary; the angle will be reduced every time it is stored in value. The cost may be free on some processors and will likely be slight on most.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to an alu operation. So skip the if( blablabla) all together and use something along the lines of (just off the top of my head)

```
val = (val % 180) * (-1 * (val<180||val>180);
```

or

```
val = (val%180) * (-1 * abs(val)>180);
```

hmmm not sure that's right and it's a little clunky but you get the idea. The (val<180 || val>180) isn't an if then and won't cause a branch miss or stall, it is an alu operation.

Will it be faster? that depends. Time different versions to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will try this one for sure!

Comment: i tried with val = val - 360*(val > 180) + 360*(val < 180); and got exactly the same times :P

Comment: Either way this is a good trick to have in your tool bag, in simple situations like this it is iffy, but in other cases it can turn ugly if then else trees into a nice short alu operation.

Answer (score 1):

For doubles I use

```
a = remainder( a, 360.0);
```

Since there is a division in there its unlikely to be fast, but I find it simple to use and clear.

I think it would be an odd program where normalising angles contributed much to the overall time taken!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo operator.

If the value is has an integer type:

```
int normalize_angle_int(int val) {
    return (val + 540) % 360 - 180;
}
```

If the value is has a floating point type:

```
#include <math.h>

double normalize_angle_double(double val) {
    return val - floor(val / 360.0 + 0.5) * 360.0;
}
```

If the argument can be below -540, the integer formula must be iterated:

```
int normalize_angle_int(int val) {
    return (val % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180;
}
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil: division is slow, but division by a constant can be implemented as a multiplication with some adjustments.

Comment: Sure, although they should keep an eye on it.